# Filtering data by child for reading || React Native || Rest Api

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, fetch-api

[image]I am using react native with firebase. where i am storing my data like this.

```
infographics-
   mdhd98djj24340-
                 cat:'health',
                 imgUrl:'something....'
   mdhd98djj24340-
                 cat:'Education',
                 imgUrl:'something....'
```

I want to read data by specific cat like i want to fetch all data where for screen where cat is equal to health. I am requesting like that but it's not showing any thing.

```
   const fetchData = async () => {
   const req = await fetch(
     'https://stratic-research-institute.firebaseio.com/infographics.json? 
     orderBy="cat"&startAt="d"&endAt="e"'
    );
   const res = await req.json();
   const vl = Object.keys(res);
   const loadedData = [];
   vl.map((item) => loadedData.push(res[item]));
   setstate({
   info: loadedData.reverse(),
   loading: false,
   });
   };
```

Comment: You have `infographics` in your query, but `info-` in your JSON. If that's not the problem, please edit your question to show the exact JSON you're querying (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: That's not issue written mistakely info instead infographic

Comment: Great. In that case please update your question for the two to match your actual code and data, and add the JSON I asked for. Without the [minimal, complete/standalone code and data that are needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to say what's going wrong.

Comment: now you can see it's updated

Comment: That's the code. I appreciate seeing more context of how you query the REST API, I was actually asking for the JSON from your database. See the link that I included in that comment too.

Comment: screen shot added now

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.